# Native browser autocomplete for textarea

Tags: html

Is it possible to enable native browser autocomplete for textareas. Would like something that works just like the input-text construct, but for textarea in order to support multi-line input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use autocomplete on textareas.

I don't know what you mean by "native browser autocomplete".

You can do autocomplete with script, using the [jqueryUI autocomplete widget](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete).

A working example:  http://jsbin.com/usuwe/2

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no browser built-in support for autocompleting textareas.