# why previous entered values appearing in textbox and not textarea?

Tags: html

I have a  clarification,probably a simple one..Once we enter some values in input type for text,date ect ,the previous values which we entered is stored.(probably a cookie) until we give autocomplete off..

Why this happens only in `textboxes` and not in `text area` by default?

Comment: Or you could try using the search engine to find a already opened question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876128/native-browser-autocomplete-for-textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something which does not exist in browsers.

If you wish to have it, you can use the [jQueryUI autocomplete widget](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) on textareas.

A working example:  http://jsbin.com/usuwe/2

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518442/autocomplete-functionality-on-a-textarea))

Comment: ,is it only a browser problem that By default text area does not support autocomplete,or is there any other reason behind this

Comment: It does not add real value to users does it?